# ASP.NET MVC: Make Session entirely cookie-less (hidden form field)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

is there some kind of standardized way which would allow me to make my ASP.NET MVC web app sessions entirely cookie*less*, but still keep session support through some standardized hidden form field value on every page (e.g. which would get parsed transparently on every request)?

P.S. I'm not looking for a URL based /(sessionid)/ solution. As stated above, this should preferably be via hidden form field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hidden form field would only work if every navigation element on your site is a button which submits the form. This would (among other things) make the back button and refresh awkward and make your site un-spiderable to search engines.

Comment: Or ajax based page retrieval.

Comment: @Dykam which is awful, and not what AJAX is for.