# Using session variable instead of hidden fields in aspx pages

Tags: session, variables, asp.net

I would love to use hidden field value but I think I am missing something to do.
Since every page refresh or staying a little bir longer on the page, the value is missing.

> [ASP.NET MVC: Make Session entirely cookie-less (hidden form field)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283650/asp-net-mvc-make-session-entirely-cookie-less-hidden-form-field)
>   ? how can i do the this cookiles suff above...?

I use hidden value to keep the url to redirect to next page.  May be i sould not keen on using hidden value, session variables are better?

Advices please.
Regards

Comment: I don't think I understand what the question is. You are talking about cookies and hidden fields and redirects, but I don't see how you want these concepts to relate. 
Could you explain:
- what you are trying to achieve
- what you have done so far
- what isn't working

Comment: Once A.aspx is requested by someone then on page_load the next page url adress is loaded ready to be use on Response.Redirect method. I used to use <input hidden> variable. But now, session varible is quite fine since the input hidden variable some times get lost on long page stand-by times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep something across the page refresh, you need to use a server side control with ViewState enabled. You have not made it clear whether for hidden fields, you are using any server side control or plain old html control. With html control, you shall have to manage the show for yourself.

Comment: server side control. after enabling viewstate what else should i do to have perfect work from the hidden varible

regards, bk

Comment: Then you can access the property of the service control on the postback the way one may use the properties of any other server controls. In the classic ASP context, we used to put the value property of hidden textboxes and accessed it whenever required on the server side. So that behaviour will still be available.